# Problemas con acentos al subir texto desde ckeditor a mysql

Tags: pdf, ckeditor

Me he vuelto loco buscando una solución a un problema que se planteaba con el cotejamiento de caracteres. Picoteando por los foros por aquí y por alla; he logrado encontrar la solución y me gustaría compartirla por si a alguien le pudiera venir bien. El problema era:

A través de un formulario empleando ckeditor, subía a la base de datos un texto que podría tener acentos u otros caracteres. Desde otra página se leía la base de datos y se devolvía un PDF. El resultado es que me devolvía el pdf con caracteres extraños o con la expresión html de las vocales acentuadas.
Lo he resuelto de la siguiente forma:

Primero he codificado todo, páginas y base de datos en UTF-8.

A la variable que recoge el texto del ckeditor y luego sube a la base de datos le he dado el siguiente tratamiento:

$puntotextogrande = $_POST['editor1'];
$puntotextogrande = html_entity_decode($puntotextogrande, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");

Con ello he conseguido que en la base de datos se guarden los acentos y no los codigos html que devuelve ckeditor.

En la página donde se forma el PDF, a la variable que recoge el dato de la bas de datos, le he dado el siguiente tratamiento:

$contenido = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1252', $contenido);

Con ello el pdf se me forma con los acentos correctamente.

Espero poder ayudar a alguien..., y gracias a todos los que escriben en los foros. Aunque no encontré la respuesta directa..., a base de componer entre las ideas de uno y otros, logré resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola carlos, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Es bienvenido contestar las preguntas propias pero se prefiere mantener el formato pregunta/respuesta. Para mas información puedes leer [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Y no olvides basarte siempre en [ask] y [answer]